# How to have 2 or more scale_linetype_manual

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

If I try to have 2 separate legends for lines using 2 separate `scale_linetype_manual`, I will get the error message above.

But then, is it not possible to have 2 separate legends to 2 different set of line categories?

Comment: Please provide a MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

tibble() %>%
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
    geom_line(data = head(iris), mapping = aes(linetype = Species)) +
    scale_linetype_manual(values = c("virginica" = 2, "setosa" = 3)) +
    new_scale("linetype") +
    geom_line(
        data = tail(iris) %>% mutate(Species2 = Species),
        mapping = aes(linetype = Species2)
    ) +
    scale_linetype_manual(values = c("virginica" = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: thank work! However, can you think of a solution that does not involve the need for an additional package/dependency?

Comment: I think the mapping one aesthetic (e.g. lien type) to one legend is hard-coded in ggplot2. `ggnewscale` will create new columns like linetype2 internally. In my example I have two different line types for virginica. This is very confusing for the reader anyways... I would avoid using different scaling at all.